# horizon orderbook calls using py-stellar-base

Tags: python-sdk

I hope this is the correct place. I am an amateur programmer and attempting to build a portfolio manager-type program on the Stellar Network. Right now I'm trying to call and parse Stellar network orderbooks using offers() in the 'Address' class of py-stellar-base. I'm not actually sure what the correct syntax looks like- is there like a 'genesis' stellar address where everything was initially mined? If so is this the address I should use in the API call? If anyone has done this before I'd love to read and learn. Open to any and all wisdom on the matter.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure if I understood you correctly, but you may be mixing up two concepts:

The `offers` within the `Address` class are giving you the offers that one Account has made, regardless of the actual asset (the naming is a bit off in the sdk, as an Address is pointing to an Account, in this case it's the same).

Example:

Account X wants to buy 10 Gold for 10 XLM and wants to sell 10 TokenX for 30 XLM.

In other words: `Offers` are a 1:n Relationship of an `Account` to `Offers` (which in turn can be `buy` and `sell`).

An `Orderbook` is a 1:n relationship of an `Asset` (e.g. `XLM` as native Asset) to another one (a concept called [Currency Pairs](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/c/currencypair.asp)). `Offers` again can be `sell` and `buy`.

The Orderbook is therefore [living on the Horizon class](https://github.com/StellarCN/py-stellar-base/blob/master/stellar_base/horizon.py#L458).

Here's an example on the testnetwork, that checks the orderbook for `DSQ` (the native token of [DSTOQ](https://dstoq.com)) against [D5BK](https://www.bloomberg.com/quote/D5BK:GR) (a real estate fund):

```
data = dict(
    buying_asset_code='DSQ',
    buying_asset_issuer='GBDQPTQJDATT7Z7EO4COS4IMYXH44RDLLI6N6WIL5BZABGMUOVMLWMQF',
    selling_asset_code='D5BK',
    selling_asset_issuer='GBPNPZFTOXZWYYKFHSUZRLWKBTBVGSTM5C7UMUEICVEAVKBXKSCZNRIC'
)

order_book = Horizon().order_book(**data)
```

Here's a graphical representation of that call (scroll down to the orderbook):

https://stellar.expert/explorer/testnet/asset/D5BK-GBPNPZFTOXZWYYKFHSUZRLWKBTBVGSTM5C7UMUEICVEAVKBXKSCZNRIC?filter=orderbook&pair=DSQ-GBDQPTQJDATT7Z7EO4COS4IMYXH44RDLLI6N6WIL5BZABGMUOVMLWMQF-1